# Какой следует добавлять замещающий текст (alt) для декоративных и других второстепенных изображений?

Tags: html, seo, поисковая-оптимизация

Какое значение атибута `alt` следует добавлять для второстепенных картинок, таких как декоративные элементы, которые не имеют прямого отношения к тематике сайта?

Если рассуждать логически, то такие картинки вообще следует скрыть от google, указав в файле `robots.txt` не индексировать конкретные файлы (мы же не хотим, чтобы кто-то ввёл в поисковике "волнистый узор", пришел на наш сайт, скачал его и использовал. Траффика будет больше, но едва ли можно то же самое сказать о конверсиях). Но я почему-то не слышал, что так рекомендуется поступать.

[Руководство google по поисковой оптимизации](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.ru/ja/ru/intl/ru/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide-ru.pdf) ничего не пишет про то, что нужно делать с декоративными элементами.

Comment: Во-первых, скрывать от гугла не нужно ничего и никогда (а если нужно, то нужно тысячу раз проверить, что это на самом деле нужно и без этого никак нельзя). Во-вторых, лично я оставлю alt пустым в таком случае

Comment: Я рекомендую вам создавать декоративные элементы со стилями CCS. Каждая картинка на веб-странице - это большой тормоз для скорости загрузки, а скорость - это мобильный трафик, который в настоящее время = 65% общего трафика.

Comment: Постараюсь! Какие-то примитивные элемента можно сделать стилями CSS, а вот со сложными узорами уже едва ли. Правда в последнем случае они часто ставятся как `background` и необходимость писать замещающий текст исчезает.

Comment: Вам решать: или сложные узоры или 65% мобильного трафика.

Comment: На лендингах и корпоративных сайтах сложные узоры, как правило, не нужны, но они часто используются в дизайне сайтов ресторанов и отелей.

Answer (score 1):

Просто оставьте пустым на декоративных элементах теги ALT.

Answer (score 1):

1. html5 сделал `alt` необязательным, поэтому его можно вообще не указывать.
2. Декоративные картинки лучше помещать в фон (через `background`), а не в тэг `img`.

Comment: «html5 сделал alt необязательным» — хм, а валидатор по сей день ругается на его отсутствие. Хотя запрета в спецификации я и правда не нашёл

Comment: Пустым если оставить, нормально будет :)

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, ну, возможно и да. Только объясни, зачем писать атрибут с пустым значением, если его можно вообще не писать с тем же эффектом?

Comment: IDE не будет раздражать сообщениями о том, что данный атрибут отсутствует xD

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, значит ide надо настроить правильно. Потому что когда он был обязателен, пустое значение тоже было невалидным.